# Inverted Powers Inequality

Tags: inequality, exponentiation

I need to prove $$a_1^{b_1}a_2^{b_2} \le b_1^{a_1}b_2^{a_2},$$
$\forall a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2$, where $a_1 > b_1, a_1 > a_2 > 0$, $b_1 > b_2 > 0$, and $a_1 + a_2 = b_1 + b_2$.

Comment: Are you somewhat familiar with concavity/convexity of functions?

Comment: not really. I'm slightly familiar with Jensen's inequality, and that's all I know about functional  inequalities

Comment: But you know the definition?

Comment: Yes, I do know the definition

Comment: Okay. Step 1: the minimum of two concave functions is concave. Step 2: $\log$ is concave and monotonically increasing, affine functions are concave. Step 3: take logarithms. Step 4: let $g(x) = \log b_2 + \frac{x-b_2}{b_1-b_2}(\log b_1 - \log b_2)$ and $f(x) = \min \{ g(x),\log x\}$. Step 5: look at $c = \frac{a_1b_1 + a_2b_2}{a_1+a_2}$.

Comment: so let's start with the 3rd step: 
$b_1 log(a_1) + b_2 log(a_2) < a_1 log(b_1) + a_2 log(b_2)$

Comment: then you define two functions, that I don't really understand. I am actually a 9th grader, so could you please give a more understandable explanation? But thank you anyway

Comment: This is one of the cases where a picture helps. You have $0 < a_2 < b_2 < b_1 < a_1$. Make a sketch of the graph of $\log$. Draw the chord rom $(b_2,\log b_2)$ to $(b_1, \log b_1)$, and the chord from $(a_2,\log a_2)$ to $(a_1,\log a_1)$. See that the latter chord lies below the former. After taking the logarithm and dividing by $a_1 + a_2$ (which I forgot to mention, but that doesn't matter since it's just a multiplication with a positive constant), what you want to show is that at $x = c = \frac{a_1b_1 + a_2b_2}{a_1+a_2}$ the second chord lies below the first one.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I did understand the solution.